# How to delete dynamodb elements using aws cli but without specifying the primary key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli

so I want to delete elements from my dyanmodb table, however, I want to delete them based on a filter expression. So if the "city" attribute is "London", the item should be deleted.

The solutions I found are all requiring exactly specifying the key, but in this case, the primary key is just a random number, so it would be hard to get them all.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: You can't do that by running aws cli commands since these commands require to provide the primary key, But, you can achieve that by creating a lambda function that will get all the keys and filter them as you wish. Be aware that this approach could run over all the items in the table and could be slow.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to delete items from a DynamoDB table is by specifying the key. If you want to delete based on an expression, you first have to scan or query the items which satisfy that expression and then delete all items returned from that scan or query by their key.

Comment: Indeed. Normally you would need to use the "Scan" operation to find the items to delete, and scan the entire table, but in some cases (depending on your workload and data distribution) it might make sense to add a global secondary index on the "city" attribute, and then you can use a cheaper "Query" operation to find the items to delete.